# How to format hours, minutes in AM/PM format

Tags: java

I am trying to format endTime which is available in minutes / hours into AM/PM format. The problematic areas seems to be between 00.00 - 1.00 in the morning and 12.00 - 1.00 in the afternoon. Not sure if this is the right approach or is there a simpler way to accomplish this?

```
public final String getEndTime() {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    buf.append(this.getEndTimeInHrs() < 13 ? this.getEndTimeInHrs() : this
            .getEndTimeInHrs() - 13).append(COLON);

    // this check is needed to prefix an additional string in front of the
    // minute (e.g. for 6 hrs 5 minutes, it will be displayed as 6:05)
    if (this.getEndTimeInMinutes() < 10) {
        buf.append(0);
    }
    buf.append(this.getEndTimeInMinutes());

    if (getEndTimeInHrs() < 12) {
        buf.append(SPACE).append(AM);
    } else if (getEndTimeInHrs() > 12) {
        buf.append(SPACE).append(PM);
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using a SimpleDateFormat with `h:mm a`?

E.g.:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
Date date = new Date(0, 0, 0, getHours(), getMinutes());
return df.format(date);
```

Comment: don't have a date as input, just time in hrs/minutes

Comment: using calendar instead of Date to construct the date

Comment: Date is deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try (provide your date instead of `new Date()`.

```
public final String getEndTime() {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    new SimpleDateFormat("h:m a").format(new Date(), buf, 0);
    return buf.toString();
}
```